# Unwanted /a> showing up on page

Tags: html, wordpress

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otDmT.png) I have an unwanted /a> showing up on a display page as Branch Line Card/a>. The link should read Branch Line Card. The error has not appeared until recently. I am not a coder in general - please help! The page link is http://guardianbp.com/branches/

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<!-- Product Catalog -->
        <?php if ( !empty( get_field('branch_product_catalog'))): ?>
        <section class="pt-medium pb-medium gray-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 "></div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 text-center">
                        <h1><span class="blue">Branch Line Card</span></h1>

                            <div class="lgbtn-icon-bg">
                                <a href="<?php the_field('branch_product_catalog'); ?>">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg-productcatalog btn-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-book fa-5x"></i>
                                    <h2><small>view the</small><br />
                                    <?php the_title(); ?><br />
                                    Branch Line Card</h2>
                                    </button>
</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you give me the page link?!

Comment: http://guardianbp.com/branches/

Comment: Search "/a>" in branches page and replace with "</a>".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mis-matched delimiter.  There appears to be a lone "< a/>" floating between:

```
         </button>
</a>
          </div>
```

Comment: I do not see this issue. Could you show me how it should look?

Comment: </button>
    # without this line ---->  </a>
    </div>  # Unless there is a matching delimiter earlier in the script?

Comment: I believe there is earlier in the script. Even eliminating this I cannot get the /a> to go away.

Comment: I think you are missing a '<h2>' in the line " Branch Line Card</h2>" (up two from the </a>). The heading formats have to match up.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue. Turns out the error was actually in an 'archive' page, and not the code above. The closing tag was listed as /a> instead of </a>. Thanks for the help!